# Android Replace the checkbox of the CheckedTextView with a button

Tags: android, checkedtextview

I was wondering if it's possible at all to replace the CheckMark of the CheckedTextView with a button, so I can click on the button and delete the item. If so, what is the recommended approach to doing this? If not, what other approaches can I take to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try making a regular listview out of your items and then create a specific listitem.xml layout for each list item to implement. This layout could then hold a delete button or any other widget you want. In code attach an onClick listener to this button to do the magic.

Comment: I've tried adding a regular text view and a button to the layout that the CheckedTextView is in and set them to invisible by default. But when I go to make them visible, the TextView shows up but I can't see the Button anywhere.